# Are there many autorelease pools created in iOS App?

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsautoreleasepool, nsrunloop

I am  having doubts on when an autoreleased object. WHen I found this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2498330/when-is-an-autoreleased-object-actually-released),

In the thread's accepted answer, the below explanation is provided for the runloop execution:

```
void int UIApplicationMain (int argc, char *argv[], NSString *principalClassName, NSString *delegateClassName) {
    UIApplication *app = /* create app using principalClassName */;
    [app setDelegate:/* create delegate using delegateClassName */];
    while (![app shouldTerminate]) {
        NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
        event = [app getNextEvent];
        [app dispatchEvent:event];
        [pool drain];
    }
}
```

Is this how runloop execution occurs?

And does it mean on each execution of runloop, a new autorelease pool will be created and released.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. Each loop there you are creating a new pool, and destroying it.

[This](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSAutoreleasePool_Class/Reference/Reference.html) explains how `drain` in a reference-counted environment, is equivalent to `release`, so it is destroyed. Next loop, you `alloc`, `init` another.